# How can i share content(Photo/Videos) to Instagram through React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sdk, deep-linking

I am trying to share photos and videos from my gallery to Instagram (as a post/story) through my React Native project. I want my code to be platform independent and also want to be able to use it in React JS(preferably using react-native-web & react-dom). I have tried using react-cli as well as expo cli. I cannot use Instagram Graph API platform as it only works for business accounts. Is there a package, or a deep-linking method that I can use to do this?

As of now, I have tried to do this using Instagram deep links and Expo (expo-image-picker & expo-linking) and have got the following output.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Image, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

const InstagramPostScreen = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert('Permission to access camera roll is required!');
      return;
    }

    const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();

    if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
      setSelectedImage(pickerResult.uri);
    }
  };

  const handlePostToInstagram = () => {
    if (selectedImage) {
      const instagramUrl = `instagram://library?AssetPath=${encodeURIComponent(selectedImage)}`;

      Linking.openURL(instagramUrl)
        .catch(() => {
          alert('Instagram is not installed on your device.');
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please select an image first.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      {selectedImage && (
        <Image source={{ uri: selectedImage }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200, marginBottom: 20 }} />
      )}

      <Button title="Choose Image" onPress={openImagePickerAsync} />

      <Button title="Post to Instagram" onPress={handlePostToInstagram} disabled={!selectedImage} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default InstagramPostScreen;
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1s0S.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45tgF.jpg)

I need to use a package/SDK deep-linking method to allow my react js webpage to directly post into Instagram.

Comment: Have you tried react-native-share with a weekly downloads of 196,222 ? Your issue may be fixed by this package. If you need further assistance ,mention me in comment @SARTHAK